# Using Displaygroups with Corona sdk storyboard

Tags: storyboard, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I´m trying to use my own displaygroup in storyboard with no luck. I bet there is an easy answer?!

```
local group = self.view --The storyboardGroup

local myGroup = display.newGroup()

for i = 0, 10 do
myObject = display.newImageRect( "mypicture.png", 20, 20 )
myObject.myName = "myObject " .. i
myGroup:insert(myObject)
end

group:insert( myGroup )
```

And now if I do:
    print(#myGroup) = 0
or 
    print(#group[myGroup]) = ERROR

How do I access myGroup???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the number of elements in a display group you should use

```
myGroup.numChildren
```

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/GroupObject/numChildren.html